# When trying to consume the url, https://vrp.api.here.com/v1/problems, the api returns error 403

Tags: token, here-api

I checked the credentials to generate the token and they are the ones generated by Here in my developer account. I am trying to consume the url https://vrp.api.here.com/v1/problems. I generated the token with [this guide](https://developer.here.com/blog/requesting-here-oauth-bearer-token-using-python).

The parameters I used were the `here.access.key.id` and the `here.access.key.secret` generated by Here in my credentials.properties file

Can you help me, please?

Comment: if it's 403, that generally indicates that you're authenticated, but not authorized to access `/v1/problems`. Could you add the code you're using to connect and the specific error responses?

Comment: Edited links and relevant tag

Comment: The error: 
<Response [403]>
{'error_description ': 'These credentials do not authorize access', 'error ': 'Forbidden'}. 
Credentials file were generated from Here REST Services. 

I consume it this way:  
hed = {'Authorization': 'bearer ' + auth_token}. 
**auth token** I generate it with  [this guide](https://developer.here.com/blog/requesting-here-oauth-bearer-token-using-python) 

**data** is a `/v1/problem` json example.

url = 'https://vrp.api.here.com/v1/problems'
response = requests.post(url, json=data, headers=hed)
print(response)
print(response.json())    

Thank you.

Comment: I already understood why. I have a developer license, so the generated token does not work for me.